# php curl with certificate and no key file or passphrase

Tags: php, curl, ssl-certificate, libcurl, x509certificate

I'm relatively new to php with curl and wanted to ask a sanity check question.

I'm attempting to post an xml file to an https server with a certificate in DER format provided by the server admin. I have also successfully converted the DER file to ascii PEM format and am receiving essentially the same error.

```
With PEM format:
* unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

With DER format:
cURL Error (58): unable to set private key file:

With DER I use: CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE => "DER"
```

My research indicates that the PHP curl also needs a key file in PEM format or at least a pass phrase. The server admin would need to provide me with one or the other.

I am aware of the outdated curl issue on Centos and some linux boxes and have upgraded curl to the latest version:
`curl 7.40.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.40.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.3 c-ares/1.10.0 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.3`

The permissions on my cer and pem files are `r--r--r--`

Am I correct about the missing key or is there a way to make such a post to an https server with only the DER or PEM certificate? Any insights much appreciated.

Here is the heart of my php script:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-Type:', 'text/xml'],
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $testorder,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE => "DER", // commented out for PEM version
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)',
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $cert_file,
);

curl_setopt_array($ch , $options);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Are you trying to use client certificate authentication (so the client's public and private key must be in the PEM) or are you trying to validate the server certificate (so the public cert of the server must be in the PEM). Looks like you set options for client certificate authentication but only provide a PEM file with a public key in it, no private key.

Comment: Thanks for the response Hans Z. I am using the cert provided to me by the server admin to authenticate myself to his server. I believe that means I am trying to use client certificate authentication as a way to authenticate myself to the server and therefore be allow to post a message. Seems I need to include a private key too which I am not.

Comment: yes, to authenticate using PKI you need a private key

Comment: Thanks Hans Z., as I thought. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you set options for client certificate authentication but only provide a PEM file with a public key in it, no private key. You need a private key as well.